# JavaScript: Create Function that Transforms Data in Nested Arrays to One Array with Multiple Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement, nested

I want to create a function called transformEmployeeData that transforms some employee data from one format to another.

argument:

```
var input = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
    ]
];
```

My desired output is:

```
var result = [
    {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk'},
    {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'}
]
```

Below is the code I tried:

```
function transformEmployeeData(employeeData) {
  // your code here

  //console.log(employeeData)

  let result = []; 

  let obj = {}; 

  //console.log(employeeData.length)

  for (let i=0; i<employeeData.length; i++){
    let element = employeeData[i];

    //console.log(element) 


    for (let k=0; k<element.length; k++){
      let indElem = element[k]

      console.log(indElem)
      //console.log(element[0])

      obj[indElem[0]] = indElem[1]; 

    }
    result.push(obj); 
  }
  return result; 
}


transformEmployeeData(input)
```

The code above produces the incorrect output below:

```
[ { firstName: 'Mary',
    lastName: 'Jenkins',
    age: 36,
    role: 'manager' },
  { firstName: 'Mary',
    lastName: 'Jenkins',
    age: 36,
    role: 'manager' } ]
```

What am I doing wrong?  I appreciate if a conceptual explanation along with correct code can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reusing the same `obj` every time through the main loop. You need to create a new object for each employee.

Simply move `let obj = {};` to the line after

```
for (let i = 0; i < employeeData.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and map the objects.

```js
var input = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']], [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]],
    result = input.map(Object.fromEntries);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: wow, didn't realize so straightforward lol